# In Laravel blade @extends layout with condition how to pass the data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

As normal extends we pass some data in the @extend like this:

```
@extends('layouts.full', [ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ])
```

I need to pass some data in the condition based @extends

```
@extends( (condition) ? 'layouts.full' : 'layouts.full2')
```

How do I pass different data in this one?

`@extends( (condition) ? 'layouts.full', [ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ] : 'layouts.full' , [ 'data2' => ['var2' => 'key2'] ])`

is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this instead:

```
@extends( (condition) ? 'layouts.full' : 'layouts.full2', [ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ])
```

If you need different data depending on the layout used, you should use IF statements instead, to avoid testing two times :

```
@if(condition)
    @extends('layouts.full', [ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ])
@else
    @extends('layouts.full2', [ 'data2' => ['var2' => 'key2'] ])
@endif
```

However, [this doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14093), so you should place this logic in the controller.

```
if(App::environment() === 'local') {
    $view = 'layouts.full';
    $data = ['class' => 'blue'];
} else {
    $view = 'layouts.full2';
    $data = ['class' => 'red'];
}

return view('viewname', compact('view', 'data'));
```

And in the view :

```
@extends( $view, $data )
```

Comment: if(App::environment() === 'local')
    extends('layouts.master', ['class' => 'blue'])
else
    extends('layouts.master', ['class' => 'red'])
endif

Comment: [This is a bug apparently](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14093). You should then place this logic inside the controller. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: thx. It worked inside controller. and also if I pass 2 values in the data and have the condition before my html tag. thxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
@extends(condition) ? 'layouts.full'
: 'layouts.full2', condition ?
[ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ] : [ 'data2' => ['var2' => 'key2'] ])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).